# Struct: field names must be string

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I made a huge, stupid, useless and complex function that gives me tons of results. Now I would like to have the output put all in a structure and here is what I am using:

```
output=struct('Date',carray{:,1},'Price',carray{:,2},'Time',carray{:,3},'a',a,'b',b,'c',c,'d',d,'e',e,'f',f,'g',g,'FreqVec',dbin{:,1});
```

and I get the following error:
Field names must be strings.
Here are some info about the output that I'd like to have in one structure:

```
variables from 'a' to 'g' are vectors of the same length (say 'n').
Date, Price and Time are three columns of a cellarray.
```

The columns have the same number of rows 'n' of the vectors
(however each cell of Price and Time is a vector with variable length)

```
dbin is a cellarray with one column and 'n' rows.
```

Each cell in dbin is a vector with variable length.

I don't really get how struct should work so I am not sure I gave you guys every info needed to understand the problem.

Hope you can help me out on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `{`,  `}` by `(`,  `)`:

```
output=struct('Date',carray(:,1),'Price',carray(:,2),'Time',carray(:,3),'a',a,'b',b,'c',c,'d',d,'e',e,'f',f,'g',g,'FreqVec',dbin(:,1));
```

When you write `carray{:,1}` you get a *comma-separated list* of the cell contents (not a column of the cell array), which is probably the source of the problem.